# Перегрузить метод по сигнатуре как в методе `next`

Tags: python

Я хочу получить метод, который может принимать (в том числе `None`) или не принимать параметр.
Например так, как это работает во встроенном методе `next`, который может принимать параметр `default`, может принимать `None` в качестве параметра `default`, а может не принимать его вовсе, вызывая `StopIterationError` в случае, если последовательность пуста.
В соответствии с [этим ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034662/python-method-overriding-does-signature-matter) на `StackOverflow` я пытаюсь перегрузить метод `touch_first` следующим образом:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

class EnumerateUtils:
    def touch_first(self, iterable):
        # Raise StopIterationError if sequence is empty
        
        iterable_iterator = iter(iterable)
        first_element = next(iterable_iterator)
        return (first_element, chain(repeat(first_element, 1), iterable_iterator))

class EnumerateUtilsOverloaded(EnumerateUtils):
    def touch_first(self, iterable, default, *args, **kwargs):
        # No raise errors
        try:
            return super().touch_first(iterable, *args, **kwargs)
        except StopIteration:
            return default

sequence = chain(range(0, 5), repeat(None, 1), range(6, 10))
empty_seq = []

def check_without_default(seq):
    util = EnumerateUtilsOverloaded()
    item = util.touch_first(seq)
    if item is not None:
        first_element, new_sequence = item
        print(first_element)
        print(list(new_sequence))

check_without_default(sequence) # -> I WANT: 0\n[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, None, 6, 7, 8, 9]
check_without_default(empty_seq) # -> I WANT: no print, but StopIterationError raised as in 'next' method without default
```

Однако, я получаю, лишь `TypeError "EnumerateUtilsOverloaded.touch_first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'default'"`, Потому что я не указал дефолтное значение для переменной `default`. Однако, если я сделаю это, то код отработает штатно, но `check_without_default(empty_seq)` ничего не выведет и **не поднимет `StopIterationError`**, как это делает метод `next`, а мне очень хотелось бы этого.

Как я могу получить желаемую логику выполнения как в методе `next`? Я не могу отличить отсутствие `default` от `default=None`.

---

В итоге, в соответствии c [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1565238/369677) @andreymal, я использовал следующий код (без классов):

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

_sentinel = object()

def touch_first(iterable, default=_sentinel, *args, **kwargs):
    iterable_iterator = iter(iterable)
    first_element = None
    if default is _sentinel:
        first_element = next(iterable_iterator)
    else:
        first_element = next(iterable_iterator, default)
    
    return (first_element, chain(repeat(first_element, 1), iterable_iterator))
```

Comment: Или запихнуть его в `*args`, или назначить значением по умолчанию какой-нибудь объект, который точно не станут передавать в качестве аргумента (типа `_sentinel = object()` где-то выше в коде и `default=_sentinel` соответственно)

Comment: Про второй способ даже в [официальной документации](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#when-can-i-rely-on-identity-tests-with-the-is-operator) написано, и он же активно используется в стандартной библиотеке

Comment: @andreymal оформите второй способ как ответ. Мне он кажется весьма приемлемым. Я подожду пару дней, если не последует ответа лучше вашего, я отмечу его как ответ.

Comment: Проверка вида `default == _sentinel` в данном случае является неверной. Если кто-нибудь очень злой создаст класс вида `class BreakYourSentinel:` `def __eq__(self, other): return True` то такая проверка выдаст `True`, поэтому нужно использовать именно `is`, который не получится сломать (и который скорее всего будет работать немножко быстрее, хотя я не измерял)

Comment: @andreymal изменил

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В подобных ситуациях часто используется такой подход — создать где-нибудь уникальный объект, который точно не будет передаваться извне как аргумент, и использовать его как значение аргумента по умолчанию.

```py
_sentinel = object()
```

Поскольку невозможно создать ещё один такой объект, для которого проверка `объект is _sentinel` вернёт `True` (и мы предполагаем, что сторонний код не станет лезть во внутренности модуля, чтобы вытянуть конкретно этот `_sentinel`) — мы можем использовать это как проверку на наличие или отсутствие переданного в функцию аргумента.

Стоит иметь в виду, что такой подход пока что [плохо дружит с аннотациями типов](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/689), но если вы не используете аннотации, то сойдёт.

```py
_sentinel = object()

class EnumerateUtilsOverloaded(EnumerateUtils):
    def touch_first(self, iterable, default=_sentinel, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().touch_first(iterable, *args, **kwargs)
        except StopIteration:
            if default is _sentinel:
                # Значение по умолчанию не указано — бросаем ошибку
                raise
            # Попали сюда — значит значение по умолчанию указано
            return default
```

Поскольку в функции есть `*args`, можно использовать альтернативный похдод — убрать аргумент `default`, тогда он попадёт в первый элемент списка `args`. Какой способ лучше или хуже — зависит от ситуации и желаемого интерфейса функции (может быть, `default` вообще должен быть [keyword-only аргументом](https://peps.python.org/pep-3102/), например?).

```py
class EnumerateUtilsOverloaded(EnumerateUtils):
    def touch_first(self, iterable, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # [1:] выкинет аргумент default, если он есть
            return super().touch_first(iterable, *args[1:], **kwargs)
        except StopIteration:
            if not args:
                # Значение по умолчанию не указано — бросаем ошибку
                raise
            # Попали сюда — значит значение по умолчанию указано
            return args[0]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Красивое решение со срезом `args`. Оказывается, это работает, даже, если `args` пуст)

Comment: Кстати, `PEP 661` был отменён? Я нашёл только библиотеку с реализацией...

Comment: @Aycon в [истории](https://github.com/python/peps/commits/main/peps/pep-0661.rst) никакой внятной движухи не видно — просто не приняли ещё, наверное

Comment: прошу прощение, я не правильно понял Ваш вопрос...